# Bash script to redirect avoid terminal output after few seconds

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I want to write a script which executes another bash script, and then redirects the script's output to the terminal after a few seconds of execution to a file instead, preventing unnecessary output being printed to the screen after initial execution.

Let's name the script process.sh. I want to write something like

```
!#/bin/bash

process.sh & # process will have to run in background 
             # since terminal has to be kept free for other processes

(sleep 5s
exec 1> cache_file) &
```

Comment: I think you'll need to permanently redirect the output of the first script to a second. The second will loop, reading output from the first and if elapsed time is under 5s send it to the terminal, otherwise to a file.

Comment: Write a small utility similar to `cat`, which copies its stdin line by line to stdout for 5 seconds, and then copies the stdin to your output file. Make sure that process.sh writes to stdout unbuffered (see _man stdbuf_ if you are on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

kINIT_DURATION=5        # seconds
kOUTPUT_FILE=cache_file

./process.sh |  {
                    start_time=$SECONDS
                    init_end_time=$((start_time + kINIT_DURATION))
                    while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
                        printf '%s\n' "$line"
                        if (( SECONDS > init_end_time )); then
                            cat >"$kOUTPUT_FILE"
                            exit
                        fi
                    done
                }
```

- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of the `while IFS= read -r line ...` loop that reads the output from `process.sh`, including the `[[ -n $line ]]` test to deal with a possibly unterminated final line of output.
- Reading input line-by-line is slow with pure Bash code.  It is particularly slow when input is from a pipeline (because it has to read character-by-character to ensure that it doesn't read past the ends of lines).  This code may be too slow if `process.sh` generates a lot of output.
- Bash strings can't hold ASCII NUL characters, so the code won't work if `process.sh` generates output that contains them.  Essentially, it only works for text, not binary, data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to log all output, not just after 5 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup process.sh </dev/null 1>out.log 2>err.log &

tail -n +1 -f out.log &
sleep 5
kill $!
```

Comment: `nohup` is useless; it does literally nothing that bash itself could not do with only shell builtins.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I should have used `#!/bin/sh`. I just meant "this is part of a script". Are you thinking of `disown` or something else?

Comment: Most of what nohup does is redirections; the rest is disown (but the disown part only matters in an interactive shell where HUP propagation is enabled by default, and is moot in a script). Since you're already redirecting all three of stdin, stdout, and stderr; and since you're in a noninteractive interpreter, you could remove the `nohup` with no difference in behavior.